# Missing sql server configuration manager

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Windows 10 and have just installed Visual Studio 2017 community edition, as u can see, sql server express 2016 localdb is installed:

[image]

However, "SQLServerManager13.msc"(or any trace of configuration manager) is nowhere to be found on my machine.

I'm suspecting it's not installed. But SQL server configuration manager is not available to download as a stand-alone application.  Please advise as to what should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This installed the [LocalDB feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017) of Express which does not install config mgr, management studio etc and is managed at the [command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqllocaldb-utility?view=sql-server-2017).

It's meant to be a very easy/quick way to have a lightweight sql server and is not meant to be used except locally and has a special connection string, hence configuration manager is not necessary.

If you want more features you can install the [full Express edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express) or SQL [Developer edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) which is good for dev/test (non-production) usage.

If you want to have an easier way to interface with the LocalDb you can download [Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) on it's own and it works with LocalDb as well.